# xetexCV vertical alignment

Tags: xetex, vertical-alignment

I'm using [Rob Oakes' xetexCV document class](http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2009/11/25/latex-cv-part1). Everything works fine except for the vertical alignment of the years. When there are two lines, the years are aligned to the bottom, I, however want them to be aligned to the top. Consider the following code where 1998-1999 would be aligned to the bottom.

```
\documentclass[english]{xetexCV}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\cvimage{/Users/bob/somepic.jpg}
\usepackage{cvsplitbib}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\cvname{Sponge Bob}
\makecvtitle
\cvsection{Academical Degress}
Learnt to make fire under water in the Pacific Ocean\\
(More precisely: Magnetic Island, Australia)\years{1998-1999}
\end{document}
```

I have found that the years-macro is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginpar{\hspace{5.13cm}\parbox{3.0cm}{\emph{#1}}}}
```

How can this be changed to be aligned to the top?

Comment: In order to make this compile on my machine, I had to comment out the `\cvimage` line and lines 26 and 27 of xetexCV.cls, which call for the _Fontin_ fonts, which I don't seem to have. Just as a hint on how to make good [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Thanks. The image name was made up anyway, but you're right.

Comment: Yes, but made up image names lead to errors. Harmless errors, but errors nonetheless. Another option would've been putting `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` before `\documentclass`, so that `graphicx` uses black rectangles instead of images.

Comment: I have a hard time in getting the _years_ alignment right.  And it's not only about long entries spanning in two or more lines. Should I open a new question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\years` is set as a `\marginpar`, i.e. a float that's typeset in the margin. It appears at the point where it is called, so if you want it to be set aligned with the first line, call it in the first line. You can even call it at the beginning of the line:

```
\years{1998-1999} Learnt to make fire under water in the Pacific Ocean\\
(More precisely: Magnetic Island, Australia)
```

[image]

On an entirely different subject: I'd recommend using an en-dash for specifying a range of years instead of a hyphen: `\years{1998--1999}`. Comparison of the results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, both (better all three ;-)) hints are very much appreciated.